# How to make a sem donut chart in Adobe Flash Builder

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, mxml, dashboard

I am using Adobe Flash Builder for my UI needs to make different types of charts.I know how to make a donut chart but i don't know how to modify the code to make the chart look like this..

[image: Bug_meter]

My MXML code for Donut Piechart..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/10/13/creating-donut-shaped-pie-charts-using-the-innerradius-style/ -->
    <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
            layout="vertical"
            verticalAlign="middle"
            backgroundColor="white">

 <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private function labelFunc(item:Object, field:String, index:Number, percentValue:Number):String {
            return item.name + ": " + '\n' + "AVG: " + item.avg;
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:ArrayCollection id="arrColl">
    <mx:source>
        <mx:Array>
            <mx:Object name="R Winn" obp=".353" slg=".445" avg=".300" />
            <mx:Object name="P Feliz" obp=".290" slg=".418" avg=".253" />
            <mx:Object name="O Vizquel" obp=".305" slg=".316" avg=".246" />
            <mx:Object name="B Molina" obp=".298" slg=".433" avg=".276" />
            <mx:Object name="R Durham" obp=".295" slg=".343" avg=".218" />
        </mx:Array>
    </mx:source>
</mx:ArrayCollection>


<mx:RemoteObject id="ro" destination="donut_piechart"/>
<mx:PieChart id="chart"
             height="100%"
             width="100%"
             innerRadius="0.5"
             showDataTips="true"
             dataProvider="{arrColl}" >
    <mx:series>
        <mx:PieSeries labelPosition="callout"
                      field="avg"
                      labelFunction="labelFunc">
            <mx:calloutStroke>
                <mx:Stroke weight="0"
                           color="0x888888"
                           alpha="100"/>
            </mx:calloutStroke>
            <mx:radialStroke>
                <mx:Stroke weight="0"
                           color="#FFFFFF"
                           alpha="20"/>
            </mx:radialStroke>
            <mx:stroke>
                <mx:Stroke color="0"
                           alpha="20"
                           weight="2"/>
            </mx:stroke>
        </mx:PieSeries>
    </mx:series>
</mx:PieChart>

</mx:Application>
```

The above code gives the following output in a web browser..

[image: Donut]

Comment: Consider of using AnyChart librarry http://anychart.com/products/anychart/gallery/Circular-Gauges.php

Comment: I want to make the above chart in Adobe Flash Builder IDE using MXML code..The example you have given is the js implementation....

Comment: AnyChart has libraries for HTML5 and for Flex. http://anychart.com/products/anychart/gallery/samples/Circular-Gauge-Color-Ranges-with-Labels.html#flash-view